# Why are my posts being rated negatively?

Tags: support, specific-question, down-votes

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [Screw falling in an elevator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377273/)

I haven't used this site much before but I asked two questions recently which were both rated -1. I have no idea why this could be and there was no constructive feedback left by the people who rated them negatively. I am only concerned about this because when I made my second question today I got a warning saying that if my posts keep getting negative ratings I may not be able to ask questions anymore which is very unfortunate, especially considering that my questions are very neutral and are simply asking for help on things I don't understand about physics.

Any advice would be appreciated. I hope this site could be more fair in that moderators would review posts and "clean up" the negative ratings on posts which don't deserve it. If you look at my two questions, you will most likely agree that they don't deserve a negative rating.

Q1: [Significant figures when adding and subtracting](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/376890/)

Q2: [Screw falling in an elevator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377273/)

Comment: If you want to discuss specific questions, there is the chatroom to use.

Comment: tbh, I really don't think your questions are that bad - I read through them both and thought that while they may appear like homework questions, they really aren't and you've put effort into them. I've upvoted them both.

Comment: The question on significant digits does not appear to show much prior research: for instance the wiki page on significant digits https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures is quite expansive and your question can be answere by reading that page alone.  Google search “significant digits” returns a number of videos and various other documents.   As to the screw falling (which I voted to close), it’s a typical homework question.  FYI I did not downvote and not sure why some did: the questions are elementary and should be closed but not “bad”.

Answer (score 4):

1. Moderators cannot invalidate votes on individual posts, so whether we agree that your posts do not "deserve" negative scores or not is immaterial.
2. Voting on SE is anonymous and explicitly left to the discretion of the voters - if the voters don't leave comments on your posts, there is no way to find out what was the reason for specific downvotes on specific posts. However, in this case I suspect you are being downvoted because your questions are close to [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583), which are off-topic here and disliked by many users.
3. If you wish to suggest that there should be some sort of requirement for downvoters to explain their votes, this has been discussed again and again on meta.SE, see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/263383) and its linked questions.